# Carrinho de compra - Alerta de contator de produtos dentro do mesmo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe algum plugin em jQuery que faz este tipo de trabalho no icone do carrinho de compra?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://github.com/ericgibb/jQuery-Badge-Count ou ainda https://codepen.io/Paul34/pen/oxQvEv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente contar quantos produtos estão adicionados (supondo que isso exista dentro de algum elemento do carrinho de compras), e adicionar esse conteúdo ao ícone com uma tag `<span>`, estilizando com CSS - sem a necessidade de um plugin específico.